# Prefetch Web Font

Tags: html, css, angular, fonts, progressive-web-apps

I'm using Angular(-Material) to create a PWA that works offline. I embed the following web font for icons:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons|Material+Icons+Outlined|Material+Icons+Two+Tone"
rel="stylesheet">
```

This in turn will set the `woff2` file sources of the `@font-faces`:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Material Icons Two Tone';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/materialiconstwotone/v112/hESh6WRmNCxEqUmNyh3JDeGxjVVyMg4tHGctNCu0.woff2) format('woff2');
}
```

This brings me to my problem: Especially the "Two Tone" font is used sparingly accross the app and as far as I can tell, the actual font (`woff2` file) is downloaded only when it is actually used somewhere (lazily). It also flickers when the first two tone icon gets used somewhere (eg. an `ngIf` that changes the class of the icon and the font is downloaded).

As the `woff2` file names are very cryptic and could potentially change inside the stylesheet, I don't want to link to them in my HTML.

How can these fonts, that are nested inside a stylesheet, be prefetched? Right now my only idea is to create a `<span>` that uses the font - in some place that it isn't visible. `display: none` cannot be used here because then the font is also not loaded.

Will it be necessary to self host the fonts for a PWA? I was hoping I could keep the CDN and let the browsercache / serviceworker do the rest.

Comment: As I don't know your Angular code, it's hard to tell. However, you might improve the timings by adding a preconnect link, such as `<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>`.

Comment: I think it has nothing to do with the angular code. I do have the preconnects for gstatic and googleapis, that changes nothing though. I'm not concerned about performance - I'm concerned about the lazy loading / caching and availability of the fonts when the PWA has no internet connection.

Comment: Yeah, me too, I'm not telling it has. Neither angular has with the cache. For some reason this font is not getting cached even when the response includes `cache-control: public, max-age=31536000`. It also happens on a regular page, thus you can discard Angular as the source of your problem.

Comment: My guess is: The font would be getting cached if it were downloaded. But the browser only downloads the CSS stylesheet, which contains the url to the font (`woff2`) which only gets downloaded if there is actually an HTML-Element that uses a CSS-Class which uses the font. I think if the CSS-Stylesheet is prefetched, all `url()` in that stylesheet should be prefetched too but they aren't.

Comment: Exactly, that's because prefetching doesn't necessarily mean fetching and executing.

Answer (score 1):

You can preload the font.

```
<link
  rel="preload"
  href="https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/materialiconstwotone/v112/hESh6WRmNCxEqUmNyh3JDeGxjVVyMg4tHGctNCu0.woff2"
  as="font"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
/>
```